# Создание массива в конструкторе Java

Tags: java, массивы, конструктор

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException* в строке **disks[i] = i;** при попытке создания объекта.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Sterzhen {
    int number;
    int disksNumber;
    int disks[];
    public Sterzhen(int number, int disksNumber){
        this.number = number;
        this.disksNumber = disksNumber;
        for (int i=disksNumber;i>=0;i--){
            disks[i] = i;
        }
    }
    void print(){
        System.out.printf("Sterzhen nomer: %d\nDiskov: %d\nDiski: 
        %s\n",number,disksNumber,Arrays.toString(disks));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sterzhen st = new Sterzhen(1,5);
        st.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не при создании ошибка, а при попытке записать значение в ячейку номер `i`. Только ты забыл инициализировать его с указанием его размера.

либо тут

```
int disks[]; //  int disks[] = new int[ЗНАЧЕНИЕ];
```

либо в самом конструкторе. Возможно должно быть так:

```
disks = new int[disksNumber];
```

Не знаю где именно, но ты обязан его инициализировать и задать конкретный размер, прежде чем туда что-то пытаться записать.

Comment: disks = new int[disksNumber]; в конструкторе перед самим циклом помогло